# Was there any method that can be called before didfinshlaunch to download data in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiapplicationdelegate, ios9.3

> I want to download the data from server before launch

I know there is a way to duplicate the launch view and load it till the success callback from service came

> But i need to know whether there is another UIapplicationprotocol
>   method which can be called before didfinsishlaunch to achieve this.Can anybody guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

**No.** As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2539831/23649), Apple requires that your application launch time be relatively short, or your app will be killed. So it's not a good idea to synchronously connect to the network before/during applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Instead, you can start an asynchronous task (see [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)) and show a progress indicator/[spinner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/) while it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(nullable NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

above method will be called before method 'didfinishLaunching' method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,there is no such an method. but you can try to use `BackgroundFetch`,it can let you download data even the app is not be launched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to solve it.
It was shown in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar