# iOS app crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, logging, crash, review

Hello my app crashed on launch on review of Apple Review Team and I didn't get crash report in `Crashlytics`, that is why only information I have is their response and crash report. So I share it with you, I didn't find proper information inside it, may be someone can read it better...

**Response:**

> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
>   attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

**Logs:**

[log_1](http://a631.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/bb/fa/58/bbfa582e-c28b-edf1-e0a9-4cbe2a836be4/attachment-4238280644663724529crashlog-B9CDB539-F9EE-4AF3-94DD-79E26ECCDB90.txt?downloadKey3=1532185464_7935aed7c2945f12a8e9c9c23eb84242), [log_2](http://a1165.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/25/f8/6b/25f86ba3-bf09-a415-5110-809c020edae3/attachment-7682249826681496875crashlog-7496DBD5-1B37-49D0-99A3-AEFE1C78EEAB.txt?downloadKey3=1532185464_46acc9e5abb4a6948bd48be000600dbf)

UPD: Here I found

> Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog
>   transgression: team.codebusters.1fit exhausted real (wall clock) time
>   allowance of 17.74 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground |
>   ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create |
>   WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed
>   total CPU time (seconds): 36.550 (user 36.550, system 0.000), 61%
>   CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.321, 2% CPU" | )

Comment: Are you making expenses in term of Computation work in the application beginning?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539831/iphone-application-launch-time-guidelines

Comment: @ReinierMelian what you mean application beginning? Is it code written in  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

Comment: did you have heavy code there?

Comment: May be you put some code that take so long to complete in didFinishedLaunchingOptions method. The error seems to be iOS killed your app because it take so long to respond.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I'm making network request here, so it is the problem. Please create an answer and I will check it as right one.

Comment: @ReinierMelian hm, however, I'm doing async network call..

Comment: @Erumaru can you post your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I will do it later, so please be in touch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid make long tasks in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` things that have a lot of CPU work should be moved to somewhere else in your app, normally you should add those methods in your first visible viewController and add a loading indicator

Apple indicates that the launch time limit is 20 seconds, so if your workload consume more than that, then your app will crash with **watchdog transgression**

Comment: Is there a way to check if I have effectively improved the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method? Somewhere to gather watchdog alloted time vs user cpu usage time?